# Python: File encoding errors

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, mediawiki, wiki

From a few days I'm struggling this annoying problem with file encoding in my little program in Python.

I work a lot with MediaWiki - recently I do documents conversion from .doc to Wikisource.

Document in Microsoft Word format is opened in Libre Office and then exported to .txt file with Wikisource format. My program is searching for a [[Image:]] tag and replace it with a name of image taken from a list - and that mechanism works really fine (Big Thanks for help brjaga!).
When I did some test on .txt files created by me everything worked just fine but when I put a .txt file with Wikisource whole thing is not so funny anymore :D

I got this message prom Python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\final.py", line 15, in <module>
    s = ' '.join([line.replace('\n', '') for line in myfile.readlines()])
  File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp1250.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 7389: character maps to <undefined>
```

And this is my Python code:

```
li = [
    "[[Image:124_BPP_PL_PL_Page_03_Image_0001.jpg]]",
    "[[Image:124_BPP_PL_PL_Page_03_Image_0002.jpg]]",
    "[[Image:124_BPP_PL_PL_Page_03_Image_0003.jpg]]",
    "[[Image:124_BPP_PL_PL_Page_03_Image_0004.jpg]]",
    "[[Image:124_BPP_PL_PL_Page_03_Image_0005.jpg]]",
    "[[Image:124_BPP_PL_PL_Page_03_Image_0006.jpg]]",
    "[[Image:124_BPP_PL_PL_Page_03_Image_0007.jpg]]",
    "[[Image:124_BPP_PL_PL_Page_05_Image_0001.jpg]]",
    "[[Image:124_BPP_PL_PL_Page_05_Image_0002.jpg]]"
    ]


with open ("C:\\124_BPP_PL_PL.txt") as myfile:
    s = ' '.join([line.replace('\n', '') for line in myfile.readlines()])

dest = open('C:\\124_BPP_PL_PL_processed.txt', 'w')

for item in li:
     s = s.replace("[[Image:]]", item, 1)

dest.write(s)
dest.close()
```

OK, so I did some research and found that this is a problem with encoding. So I installed a program Notepad++ and changed the encoding of my .txt file with Wikisource to: UTF-8 and saved it. Then I did some change in my code:

```
with open ("C:\\124_BPP_PL_PL.txt", encoding="utf8') as myfile:
        s = ' '.join([line.replace('\n', '') for line in myfile.readlines()])
```

But I got this new error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\final.py", line 22, in <module>
    dest.write(s)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp1250.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufeff' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

And I'm really stuck on this one. I thought, when I change the encoding manually in Notepad++ and then I will tell the encoding which I set - everything will be good.

Please help, Thank You in advance.

Comment: What codec did Notepad++ think it was when you opened the input file? Why did you not use that encoding to read the file (without changing it to UTF-8) in Python itself?

Comment: Hi, the codec is "ANSI as UTF-8" - I don't know what that means and I don't know how to set this codec in Python open() function, do You know what is that ? And how to set it in Python ?

Comment: `UTF-8` is just fine; there is no ANSI codec, really, it just means 'local Windows codepage dialect' which can be anything between `cp1250` and `cp1255` IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Python 3 opens a text file, it uses the default encoding for your system when trying to decode the file in order to give you full Unicode text (the `str` type is fully Unicode aware). It does the same when writing out such Unicode text values.

You already solved the input side; you specified an encoding when reading. Do the same when *writing*:  specify a codec to use to write out the file that can handle Unicode, including the non-breaking whitespace character at codepoint U+FEFF. UTF-8 is usually a good default choice:

```
dest = open('C:\\124_BPP_PL_PL_processed.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

You can use the `with` statement when writing too and save yourself the `.close()` call:

```
for item in li:
     s = s.replace("[[Image:]]", item, 1)

with open('C:\\124_BPP_PL_PL_processed.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as dest:        
    dest.write(s)
```